# Sentencia where dentro de un with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una relación muchos a muchos entre `properties` y `people`, en su tabla pivote tengo el id de la tabla, el `property_id`, el `person_id`, y tengo un campo tinyint (boolean) llamado `main_owner`.
Para una consulta, requiero todos los `properties` sus `people` solo si en su tabla pivote, el campo `main_owner` tiene valor 1 (true).

Sucede que no se como ordenar toda la sentencia, para acceder a la tabla pivote use el metodo `withPivot` dentro del modelo.

Metodo del modelo Property:

```
public function people() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class, 'people_properties', 'property_id', 'person_id')
    ->withPivot('main_owner');
}
```

Lo que llevo hasta el momento del método en el controlador:

```
public function getProperties() {
    $properties = Property::whereDoesntHave('propertyType', function ($query) {
        $query->where('nombre', 'parqueadero');
    })
    ->with('people', function (query) {
        //Aqui imagino que debe haber un for recorriendo people y validando que main_owner
        //tenga el valor especificado, pero no se como acceder a people, y no se si asi seria
        //la forma correcta
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ->get();

    return $properties;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes de hacer es lo siguiente:

```
public function getProperties() {
    $properties = Property::whereDoesntHave('propertyType', function ($query) {
        $query->where('nombre', 'parqueadero');
    })
    ->with(['people' => function ($query) {
        //Reemplaza el nombre con el valor real
        $query->where('nombre_tabla_pivote.main_owner', 1);
    }])
    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ->get();

    return $properties;
}
```

Nota que para acceder a la propiedad de la tabla pivote bastó solo colocar el nombre de la tabla pivote seguido de un punto y el nombre de la propiedad, tal y como lo harías en una consulta SQL regular.

Comment: Disculpa la pregunta, pero, en donde dice nombre_tabla_pivote, es posible acceder debido a que en el modelo tengo el "withPivot"? O es por otra cosa?

Comment: @SantiagoBueno Tienes que reemplazar `nombre_tabla_pivote` por el nombre real de tu tabla pivote, no colocaste el nombre en tu pregunta así que no pude saber cual es, el método `withPivot` es para que especifiques atributos pivote (los cuales, son datos extra aparte de los ids que conectan a tus tablas), lo que hace que puedas acceder a ellos en ese `where` es debido al tipo de relación `belongsToMany`, `withPivot` solo te deja acceder a esos atributos para cuando manejes los registros, ejemplo: `$property->pivot->main_owner;`, sin el `withPivot` esa línea de código te devolvería error.

Comment: Entiendo, muchisismas gracias, me funciono perfectamente, y aclaraste mi duda respecto al withPivot